# python series how to extract the index string

Tags: python

I have series with an index as country names.
How can I access the 3rd largest country?
I came up with something like `countries.sort_values(ascending=False)[3:4]` but it gibes me also the first column and I need only the string from the index
but I am pretty sure there is a cleverer way to do it.

```
Country
Australia              2.3316e+07
Brazil                2.05915e+08
Canada                3.52399e+07
China                 1.36765e+09
France                6.38373e+07
Germany               8.03697e+07
India                 1.27673e+09
Iran                  7.70756e+07
Italy                 5.99083e+07
Japan                 1.27409e+08
South Korea           4.98054e+07
Russian Federation      1.435e+08
Spain                 4.64434e+07
United Kingdom         6.3871e+07
United States         3.17615e+08
dtype: object
```

Comment: What data type is your "series"... a list of strings, a dictionary, other?

Comment: @RoryDaulton how do I check it?

Comment: If this is an assignment, that would be part of your problem description. If you got this information from a file or a web page and are storing it in a variable in your program, you as the programmer must know what the data type is. If the info is still in a file or web page, say so and explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new dict, switch keys and values.

```
my_dict2 = dict((y,x) for x,y in my_dict.iteritems())
```

Then sort the keys and select 3'rd value

```
number = sorted(my_dict2.keys())[3]
```

Look up the country with the 3'rd value.

```
solution = my_dict2[number]
```